# Error converting data type varchar to int error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_Registrations]
    @type varchar(50) = null,
    @Customer_ID int = null,
    @Customer_Name varchar(50) = null,
    @Email varchar(50) = null,
    @Password varchar(50) = null,
    @Mobile varchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @type = 'select'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM ssshub..Customer_Master
    END 

    IF @type = 'specific'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM ssshub..Customer_Master 
        WHERE Customer_ID = @Customer_ID
    END

    IF @type = 'insert'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer_Master]([Customer_Name], [Email],[Password], [Mobile], [SDate])
        VALUES ('@Customer_Name', '@Email', '@Password', '@Mobile', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    END
END
```

And my table

This is working fine

This query works fine but when I am trying to insert it using stored procedure it throws an error.

I have an `identity` specification for `customer_id` on so no need to insert it

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer_Master] ([Customer_Name], [Email], [Password], [Mobile], [SDate])
VALUES('ewcewc', 'dewdw@dwc.com', 'dewdwd', '9999999999', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Now when I am trying to execute my stored procedure with the following statement

```
 exec customer_registrations 'insert', 'dsad', 'test@test.com', 'pass', '9999900000'
```

I get:

> Error converting data type varchar to int

Comment: The problem is with column Customer_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pass null value in procedure while you insert the data in table. Run the procedure below way while inserting data in table. you should me manage all the parameter of procedure. you are not passed value of `Customer_ID`, so that's way error occur.

```
EXEC [dbo].[Customer_Registrations] 'insert',null,'ewcewc', 'dewdw@dwc.com', 'dewdwd', '9999999999'
```

Answer (score 3):

Lining up your *arguments* with the *parameters*:

```
'insert'          -> @type varchar(50)
'dsad'            -> @Customer_ID int    
'test@test.com'   -> @Customer_Name varchar(50)
'pass'            -> @Email varchar(50)
'9999900000'      -> @Password varchar(50)
                  -> @Mobile varchar(50) = null
```

...you can see that `'dsad'` has no way of being understood as an `int`. Maybe there's a problem elsewhere as well, but at the very least, the stored procedure is not being called correctly.

**Update**:

If your intent was to omit *some* arguments that aren't relevant in a certain case, you have to use named parameters; otherwise, arguments can only be applied in the same order the parameters appear:

```
exec customer_registrations 
  'insert', 
  @Customer_Name = 'dsad', 
  @Email         = 'test@test.com', 
  @Password      = 'pass', 
  @Mobile        = '9999900000';
```

Comment: In your Insert query you did't specify "Customer_ID" that way it works. as per my knowledge you cant pass nvarchar value to int type in procedure. see you pass "dsad" as string where the parameter at that place in procedure having int datatype

Comment: in stored procedure even i didn't specify customer_id

Comment: @DhavalBulsara, that's not relevant. The arguments in the stored procedure call are simply assigned to the stored proc's parameters, then those parameters are used in the insert statement. One does not relate to the other. If you try to skip some parameters, SQL Server will have no idea which ones you mean unless you use the named arguments syntax (adding shortly)

Comment: @Jacob That Worked too!

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Database Test

Create Table Employee
(
EmpId int identity(1,1) not null primary Key,
EmpName varchar(50),
Address varchar(50),
MobileNo int
)

Select * From [dbo].[Employee]

Alter Table [dbo].[Employee] Alter Column MobileNo Bigint

Insert into [dbo].[Employee] values('Harsh Kumar','Banglore','9748342075')

Create Proc MyProc
As
Select * From [dbo].[Employee]

EXEC MyProc

Create Proc SP_GetEmp
@EmpId int,
@EmpName varchar(50),
@Address varchar(50),
@MobileNo int
As
Insert into [dbo].[Employee](EmpId, EmpName, Address, MobileNo) Values(@EmpId, @EmpName, @Address, @MobileNo)

EXEC SP_GetEmp 'Rahul Kr','Pune', 8250707544

EXEC MyProc

Error:- Error converting data type varchar to int.
```